# How to select one of the tables from two tables with the same class value?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On the UI I see two tables, each having the same class value, how to select one of the tables from these?

Like:

```
<table class="content-grid" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="License Requirements by Type">
<table class="content-grid" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="Users and Unassigned devices">
```

If I have to select the First table How do I do it. Can I do it using xpath?

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='content-grid']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it should be `//table[@summary='License Requirements by Type']` and `//table[@summary='Users and Unassigned devices']` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with xpath as below:

```
//table[@class='content-grid'][1]
//table[@class='content-grid'][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Css selector will help you to select as below.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table[summary='License Requirements by Type']"))
```